# Fail to import scipy.spatial.voronoi

Tags: import, scipy, voronoi

I'm trying to use the Voronoi tessellation from scipy

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html

but python won't import it

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Voronoi
```

however, I don't have a problem importing other classes from scipy.spatial

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
```

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  `Voronoi` was added in version 0.12.0 of scipy.

Comment: I was using version 0.11.0. I upgraded it and now everything is working. Thanks.